# What version of Python does XBMC 12.0 (Frodo) use?

Tags: python, xbmc

It would be more appropriate to ask this question on the [XBMC forum](http://forum.xbmc.org/), but it is down for maintenance and weekends don't last forever!

What version of Python does XBMC 12.0 use and/or require a plugin to be written in?  The `prerequisites` section [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=How-to%3aDebug_Python_Scripts_with_Eclipse) states:

> Python interpreter 2.4 (use the same version as XBMC or version <= 2.7
>   ) install on the machine running Eclipse

... which suggests that some unknown version of XBMC once required a version of Python `2.4 <= N <= 2.7`

On the other hand, the `scripts and plugins section` [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMC_v12_%28Frodo%29_API_changes) suggests that maybe version `2.1.0` or `2.0.0` may be required/used.

Comment: Can you make a test plugin and add `print(__import__('sys').version)` to the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what platform and with what options XBMC is built with. Since the configure script [required at least 2.4](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/Frodo/configure.in#L857) and 3.x is generally not compatible, that indeed leaves 2.4 - 2.7. By default, you'll get the one installed as a *-dev* package on the compiling machine, which will most likely be the default one of your distribution.

2.1.0 is just the version number of the Python add-on, and unrelated to the Python installation itself.

Comment: `2.1.0 is just the version number of the Python add-on` <- I suspected that as I was reading, but I wasn't for sure.  Thanks for clarifying.  I'm still trying to understand the relationship between XBMC and Python though.  Docs say XBMC has a "Python engine", but XBMC does not install Python on my machine, but there is an `XBMC/system/python/lib` folder.